# Identity Server v3 can't find endpoints

Tags: owin, thinktecture-ident-server

I’m trying to get Identity Server v3 up and running. Below is what I've done.

1. Created an empty ASP.NET web project
2. Copied the StartUp and
   config files from the SelfHost (Minimal) (http://goo.gl/ojOjSJ)
   sample project
3. Installed the following Nuget packages: OWIN,
   Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, and
   Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3
4. Add the [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))] attribute

When I run locally and try to hit one of the endpoints (/core/.well-known/jwks), I get “The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.” I know startup is running because I can set a breakpoint and it hits it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you are better off with using the github issue tracker because idsrv is still under development.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by installing the following hotfix for handlers with extensionless URLs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/980368/a-update-is-available-that-enables-certain-iis-7.0-or-iis-7.5-handlers-to-handle-requests-whose-urls-do-not-end-with-a-period